Is it possible to make a No-DELETE replica/follower database?
I would like to allow an application's database to execute DELETE statements. However, for analytics purposes, I would like to keep all data, even deleted data.
I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do this. Preferably a not-uncommon way.
My initial thought on a DIY approach this would be to use the Write-Ahead Log + a logical replication slot plugin.
The plugin would need to do 2 things:

Adjust all CREATE TABLE statements such that they also add a ___deleted_at column
Change all DELETE statements to UPDATE statements which would SET ___deleted_at = NOW()

However, I've never interacted with WAL nor logical replication. I'm sure I'd run into all sorts of problems with the above. Even just handling cascaded DELETE
Is there any precedence for this type of replication?

That is simple using logical replication. When you create the publication, simply exclude delete from the publish option:
CREATE PUBLICATION some_name FOR ALL TABLES
   WITH (publish = 'insert, update, truncate';

Note that that may lead to replication conflicts. Imagine the following sequence of statements on the publisher (where id is assumed to be the primary key):
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (42, 'joe');
DELETE FROM tab WHERE id = 42;
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (42, 'joan');

Since the DELETE statement is not replicated, you will get a primary key conflict on the subscriber that will stop the replication.

Yep, was figuring the leader would also never be able to use direct primary key assignment (auto-increment only), which i suppose is a dangerous thing to hope for in perpetuity even though that's how it is now. Also, follower would have to be adjusted to not have fk constraints. The only other problem with this is the follower still needs be aware of what was deleted (see ___deleted_at in OP) for the analytics to be useful.
